# Best way to define constant value in template

Tags: c++

When I implement `vector3` class, I have a simple question.

There are several ways to define a constant value in a template. What are these differences? And which one should I use?

`template<typename T>`;

1: `T{1}`

2: `T{1.0f}`

3: `T{1.0}`

4: `static_cast<T>(1.0)`

Comment: If you use templates and classes, why did you tag your question with the C language tag? Please don't spam with unrelated tags.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking. Where do you need this constant value? What are you using it for? `constexpr T = 1` will work in a lot of scenarios, but it's hard to know if that's right.

Answer (score 0):

None of those make a difference, unless you have a type that converts from int differently than from float. I prefer the first, as it is the briefest

Comment: I think the only difference is that 4th option won't work with an `explicit` constructor.